# Multi-branch pipeline - one project per folder

Tags: git, svn, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am currently trying to migrate my repositories from SVN to GIT and I encountered a problem while trying to setup the configuration for the Jenkins multi branch projects.

I have a repository that contains multiple configuration in a single branch. Each configuration in a different sub-directory. The configurations have no relation to each other, other then that they do similar things (in that case they package installers with different configurations).

Now I got this working nicely using SVN with a Jenkins multi-branch pipeline project. I have it setup to fetch a specific directory inside the trunk and treat all sub-directories as branches to create the entries. Now that does not seem to work anymore with GIT, since I can't set anything else to be pulled other then references. Sub-Directories aren't a option from what I can see.

So the only thing I can think of is to put every configuration into unrelated branches. But that means creating a lot of branches. In addition I need every single configuration at least in a develop and a master branch... that means even more unrelated branches (well there are always groups of two that would be related) but creating releases like this will the prone to errors.

Is there any way around this? And way to automatically create and orphan such projects based on sub directories with git?